# Setup Virtual Home Network

Tags: home-networking

I'm trying to set up my network where all of my traffic goes through my virtualized PFSense and virtualized Snort, then to the internet.  Can you please check my graphic and see if I am making sense?  If I understand how this works, when my host connects to google.com, it first goes through the LAN interface on pfSense, then passes through Snort, then on to google.  In order to do that though, I have to have my LAN interface IP as the default GW on my host or else it won't go through the pfSense and Snort.  Is that right?

Additionally, how can I block all IPv6 on my network if the random device in my network isn't set up with the default GW of my pfSense interface?  Like my Fridge or anything else I can't easily get in to and change the GW.
[image]

Comment: If I may ask where the 192.168.1.5 address is coming from. Looking as your diagram it seems that you would use 192.168.1.10 as your default GW. Also it seems like it would be more prudent to set PFSense to 192.168.1.1 and then set your other server / software to something else say 192.168.1.254

Comment: Sorry about the diagram error. I meant to put the GW at 192.168.1.10 for my host.  As for your response on the .254, I don't fully understand that.  The circle at the top is my router and the current GW for the entire network (192.168.1.1).  Why do you think it would be more prudent?

Comment: Based on your question you are wanting to send all traffic through PFSense, so make it the .1 address and make your router (the circle some ip address for ex .254 and snort to .253. I assuming nothing but pfsense is communicating with these?

Comment: Well the trick is not to let anything communicate with the router unless it goes through inspection by Snort and pfSense. What's wrong with leaving the IPs the way they are above?  Not challenging you, just trying to understand.

Comment: There is a fundamental error in your understanding of how this works. Unless you plan on placing your snort/pfsense in some sort of passthrough/bridge mode and physically wiring everything behind it (in which case you don’t change gw at all), you have to have two different subnets on each side of the pfsense box.  Your network isn’t hooked up in one long daisy chain like you drew it. To do this right it’ll take two subnets. Like 192.168.1.x on external side, and 192.168.2.x on your internal side. The pfsense box will sit in the middle of each. It will not work as you have described it.

Comment: Even if you did hook this up like you describe only traffic flowing in one direction would pass through pfSense. Asymmetric routing would cause traffic in the other direction to completely bypass your pfsense. In general asymmetric routing is bad and can cause issues.

Comment: @Appleoddity Sorry it took me a few days. Had to focus on my other class project.  So I understand what you're saying.  Does it have to be 2 networks because the FW is the block into the network, so it has to be separated?  Additionally, if I want to use Snort in IDS mode, will I need to do the same type thing?  Ext subnet for snort, int subnet for snort/FW, internal for hosts?

Comment: I updated the main post with the new network diagram broken out as I think I understand your explanation.